# How to write a java EJB async service?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee

I tried to do this

```
@Consumes(APPLICATION_XML)
@Produces(APPLICATION_XML)
public class TestService {
    @POST
    @Path("querymember")
    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> queryMemberAysnc(Member member) {
        return new AsyncResult<>(businessLogic.query(member));
    }
}
```

When I do this in synchronous way, it works fine. But once I change it to async, it is giving me "org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor.writeResponseErrorMessage No message body writer has been found for response class AsyncResult."

I couldn't find any other example on writing an aysnc operation with EJB. Any hint on how I can fix this in a right way?

Comment: @BalusC honestly, I can't agree with anything you said there, but it doesn't matter. I was simply trying to figure out the correct syntax how to write an async operation. If the annotation is wrong, just simply direct me to the right document on where I should put it. If I should wrap my internal query() method in an async way, just provide me hint how to do it. your other comments were just pointless...sorry to say that

Comment: Documentation example [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/asyncMethodOfEJB/AsyncMethodEJB.html) Also your example is missing an EJB annotation on the class level (`@Stateless`). Is it intentionally omitted?

Comment: I don't think you can use Future/AsyncResult with a web service.  Are you really trying to do this via web service or just calling an EJB method directly?  If directly, then you don't need @Consumes/@Produces/@POST/@Path.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous method should be implemented inside EJB Session Bean, because web service call result of type Future make no sence.

So, the example idea could be:
1. Implement EJB Session Bean, with @Asynchronous method
2. Implement method in your web service, which will call asynchronous method -> save returned 'Future' object somewhere in your storage by key (static Map, etc) -> return this key to client
3. Implement method in your web service for getting a result by key, which will retreive 'Future' object by key from your storage -> check if Future have result -> return the result to client

The client should periodically check for results, until asynchronous method invocation is finished, and result is returned.